# как инициализировать строку полученную из класса ModelMap

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myjsp_page",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String new_orders(ModelMap model) {

  model.addAttribute("message", "тут будет json");
  return "myjsp_page";

}
```

из jsp полученную вот эту строку <"тут будет json"> с помощью ${message}
нужно инициализировать на String.т.е мне нужно вот так:

```
String str = ${message};
<%= str%>
```

как можно достать строку `${message}` чтобы работать с ним в java(jsp) коде?

Comment: Так не работает, нужно убрать последнюю строчку.

Comment: да.это был пример того что хочу сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал вот так.Работает.

```
<%
  ServletRequest rq =  pageContext.getRequest();
  String str = String.valueOf(rq.getAttribute("message"));
%>
<% = str %>
```